# PHP setcookie() not always overwriting value

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I have been pulling my hair out over an intermittent problem. I am in the process of dissecting the problem but being intermittent, it's taking a while. I've found a hack that works, I just don't know why and it's bugging me, perhaps someone can spot a pattern and take a guess at the cause:

**Summary:** This line doesn't always work:

```
setcookie('myhash',$aHash,0,MYSUBDIR);
```

**Background:** It often starts happening when I come back to the PC after some time, having left the Firefox tab open and perform an AJAX call like add to basket. (WAMP server, localhost, accessed by local IP 192.x.x.x, untested elsewhere). After which, I turn on debugging output and can refresh pages etc, but the cookie never gets set. All pages including ajax are in MYSUBDIR or subdirectories of it.

**Steps taken to debug**: I have taken great care to ensure the pages' debug output and all other output is sent to the buffer: I call `ob_start()` before anything else whatsoever, for both AJAX and pages, and later call `ob_end_flush()`. From other SO questions, this seems to be the common fail.

The hacky workaround I have found to work is to add this line immediately before the one mentioned above:

```
setcookie('myhash',$aHash,time()-1000);
```

Strangely, using this line instead of the workaround above, does NOT work:

```
setcookie('myhash',$aHash,time()-1000,MYSUBDIR);
```

**Thoughts about causes:**

1. Are there times when the `MYSUBDIR` constant isn't always set, so perhaps defaulting to setting the cookie with the path '/' - although I have error reporting to E_ALL, verbose output and also into a DB, and have not seen any such errors logged.
2. The 'myhash' cookie key is hard coded and only in one place in my code, so I don't think that's the problem - besides, I call `var_dump($_COOKIE)` (after `ob_start()`) and don't see anything wrong with the cookie key.
3. cookie permissions: access by IP and 'localhost': I don't think it's this because in a single page load, I read and attempt to set (overwrite) the cookie. I can do this repeatedly by refreshing the page, and it keeps displaying the value that I am unable to overwrite.

Can anyone spot likely causes for the inability to overwrite the cookie?

Comment: `setcookie('myhash','',time()-1000,MYSUBDIR);` working?

Comment: Ever figure this out? I have the same thing with a rememberme cookie not being overwritten?